# assignment in SystemVerilog, compilation error - token is 'assign'

Tags: system-verilog

I have this code:

```
integer [31:0]R;
integer [15:0]R_f1;
integer [15:0]R_f2;

assign R_f1 = R[15:0];
assign R_f2 = R[31:16];
```

But it is not compiled because of `assign`.
What changes do I need to do ? It can also be in the header file.

Answer (score 2):

There was a bug in the original implementation of Verilog-XL that it ignored the packed dimensions of `integer` declarations. And `integer/int/byte` did not have a fixed size. For these reasons, SystemVerilog disallows specifying packed dimensions for any of these built-in types. Use `bit` or `logic` instead.

Also, since you tagged this with SystemVerilog make sure the file has a *.sv suffix. An alternative to what you are trying to do is

```
integer [31:0]R;

let R_f1 = R[15:0];
let R_f2 = R[31:16];
```

Comment: It works. Could you explain what difference between assign and let ? @dave_59

Comment: I don't understand why I can't use with integer ? if I change integer to logic or bit then it still doesn't work. @dave_59

Comment: `let` is a symbolic substitution for an expression; there is no assignment, no extra signals created. It like a more formal text macro because it has a scope and the substitution must be a proper expression, Text macros are global and can be almost any arbitrary text.

Comment: You need to show a more complete example with the exact error message. If you change to `bit` or `logic` and it still complains just about the `assign` statement, then there is something else you are not showing the could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. Depending on the language you use. In verilog, only the net types can be assigned using continuous assignment. `integer` is not a net type, therefore theses assignments are not allowed in verilog. I guess you compiled your code in `verilog` mode and got the message about assignment statements.
2. Also packed dimensions on `integer` types are not allowed. So, the following declaration is illegal: `integer [31:0]R;`. Some compilers will just ignore the declaration. All integers are 32 bit wide in any case.

So, to fix it in `verilog` mode you can use `always @*` instead:

```
integer R = 10;  
integer R_f1;
integer R_f2;

always @* R_f1 = R[15:0];
always @* R_f2 = R[31:16];
```

Though by the sound of your initial question, you need to use a different type of the data type, which allows you to have real vectors. In `verilog` they are `reg` and one of the net types, i.e. `wire`. With `wires` you can use `assign` statement, with `reg` you need to use always blocks. Something like the following:

```
reg[31:0] R = 10;   
reg[15:0] R_f1;
reg[15:0] R_f2;

always @* R_f1 = R[15:0];
always @* R_f2 = R[31:16];
```

Since you marked your question as a system verilog question, you can use one of the system verilog types, i.e. `logic` or `bit`. If you use those, you can apply both, `assign` or `always` blocks to them. BTW, `assign` will also work for integeres.

```
logic[31:0] R = 10;   
logic[15:0] R_f1;
logic[15:0] R_f2;

assign R_f1 = R[15:0];
assign R_f2 = R[31:16];
```

just make sure that you compile in a system-verilog mode.

Comment: It doesn't work. I use with vcs filename.sv -sverilog @Serge

Comment: @Alex which tool did you use to compile? How did it not work?

Comment: and how did it fail?